# How to update Sysctl settings?

Tags: ubuntu, sysctl

How to update Sysctl settings with

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576
```

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current inotify user instance limit, with the following:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
```

Similarly, the current inotify user watch limit can be checked as follows:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Update the limits
You can update the limits temporarily, with the following commands (setting the values to 8192 and 524288 respectively in this example):

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=8192
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
sudo sysctl -p
```

In order to make the changes permanent, i.e. to persist a reboot, you can set `fs.inotify.max_user_instances=8192` and `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` in the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

After updating the limits, you can validate these on the host again, as above, with `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances` and `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches.`